# Image still rotated after Editing Exif Data

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, exif, android-exifinterface

In My app the User captures an image from the gallery or camera it is then converted to PDF, Now my problem is that images captured from the samsung devices are rotated,

I am trying to edit the exif data but it does not work,

there is no errors the image just stays rotated

I am new to android and the entire EXIF data thing goes over my head, some advice would be awesome

```
   private void PDFCreation(){
            PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo;
            PdfDocument.Page page;
            Canvas canvas;
            int i;
            for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++)  {
                pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(992, 1432, 1).create();
                page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
                canvas=page.getCanvas();
                image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(i));
                image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 980, 1420, true);
                image.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
                canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);

                ExifInterface exif;
                int rotate = 0;

                try
                {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(selectedPhoto);
                    int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (exifOrientation)
                    {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotate = 90;

                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotate = 180;
                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotate = 270;
                            break;
                    }


                    if (rotate != 0)
                    {
                        int w = image.getWidth();
                        int h = image.getHeight();

                        // Setting pre rotate
                        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                        mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                        // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
                        try
                        {
                            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
                        }
                        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w/2, h/2, mtx, false);

                        }

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                image=createBitmap(image, 0, 0,
                        image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                        matrix, true);

                canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
                document.finishPage(page);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String directory_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
            File file=new File(directory_path);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
            String targetPdf=directory_path + timeStamp + ".pdf";
             filePath=new File(targetPdf);
            try {
                document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString());
                Toasty.error(this, "Error making PDF" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            document.close();


        }
```

Comment: You edit exif data before you start with the PDF, don't you? Make sure (with debugger, or console log) that the `selectedPhoto` is the file you expected (on the face of it, it should be `list.get(i)`) and that the exif attribute there is what you wrote before.

Comment: The ExifInterface I believe is the EXif data i edit in the code then there is an IF statement, that code is all I have for the EXIF data

Comment: You only *read* the Exif information. If nobody put the correct orientation flag for you, then **rotate** will be 0

Comment: @AlexCohn , how can I edit the EXIF data then, so that the image is rotated correctly?

Comment: You can edit EXIF header with **ExifInterface**, but you must know the expected orientation to put there. On the face of it, you don't have this information when you create the PDF, probably it's too late. If you get the picture from gallery, and the orientation flag is not correct, there is nothing you can do.